# Hiving problems sending Sms with Java android

Tags: java, android, sms

I want to send an sms form an android device using java.

```
    public static void sendSms(String command, String duration, String hour, String minute){
        SmsManager smsManager =  Context.getSystemService(SmsManager.class);
        smsManager.sendTextMessage("0782890411", null, "12345678/on-25/99:99", null, null);
    }
```

I'm using the above code because `SmsManager.getDefault();` is deprecated. but for some reason `Context.getSystemService(SmsManager.class);` gives me

**Non-static method 'getSystemService(java.lang.Class)' cannot be referenced from a static context
Call requires API level 23 (current min is 21): android.content.Context#getSystemService**

What's the problem with this code?

Comment: Do you added sms permission?

Comment: ```ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
``` I added this in main activity

Comment: also added in manifest?

Comment: I solved the issue, I added it to the manifest, and added the request for the permission in the code.